# How to place the data API into the Ant Design Cascader?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have previously managed to place and retrieve data, but for the feature menu and dropdown ...the image below

[image]

well, the problem is how to retrieve or place data in the cascader? I take the data from the ant design example ... which I am confused about how to retrieve data from the API ...
[image]

I don't understand how to take or place data from the API to Cascader in design https://ant.design/components/cascader/,

I share the code directly using codesanbox.io this url
https://codesandbox.io/embed/distracted-hodgkin-8lmt6

Answer (score 2):

Map `allCategory` `id` prop to `value` and `name` to `label` prop:

```js
  render() {
    const options = this.state.allCategory.map(category => ({
      value: category.id,
      label: category.name
    }));

    return <Cascader options={options} />;
  }
```

Demo:

[image: Edit Q-56619059-SO]

Comment: how to display children?

Comment: Which children? `Cascader` doesn't accept children, refer to api: https://ant.design/components/cascader/